# Google SignIn on iOS - Gain new ServerAuthCode

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm logging in my user on iOS like this:

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kGoogleClientID; // From services.plist
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID = kGoogleServerID; // from api console, web application

// those two are not needed for the auth code
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = @[@"email", @"profile"];

[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;

[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn]
```

After the login screen appeared and the user logged in, I can obtain a serverAuthCode like this:

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {

    // Perform any operations on signed in user here
    if (nil == error)
    {

        NSLog(@"Google Server Auth Code:%@", user.serverAuthCode);
    }
}
```

This works fine for the first time, but if the user restarts the app and logs into Google again, the Login screen does not need to appear again - since the user is already known. Therefore signIn succeeds instantly, but there's no new auto code. Also sometimes we might need another serverAuthCode to perform another login on the server, but don't want to bother the user with another login screen.

How can one get a new serverAuthCode for an already logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the .NET Google SignIn SDK for iOS.

This seems to be related to [Google Sign-In for iOS: serverAuthCode is intermittently missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147176/google-sign-in-for-ios-serverauthcode-is-intermittently-missing)

In a comment someone suggested calling `signOut` right before calling `signIn`.

It fixed the issue for me (using the .NET SDK), hope it does for you too. It forces the user to connect again though.

Comment: Agree. On my side I only need to fetch this token once and work with refresh tokens thereafter so this is an acceptable solution, but I can understand if it does not match your need. 

That is a workaround more than a solution. But what we are sure is that this is a bug from the SDK and it probably will not be fixed according to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63673654