# Google Sign-In for iOS: serverAuthCode is intermittently missing

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

We first reported this [on a Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63673654) but were redirected here.

We have been using Google Sign-In for iOS in our iOS app. When a user signs in, our GIDSignInDelegate receives a call to `sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)`.

Until this afternoon, the GIDGoogleUser that we receive in this call has always contained a non-nil `authentication?.idToken` and a non-nil `serverAuthCode`, or else `error` is non-nil and contains information about why authentication failed.

Beginning last week, intermittently, signing in results that method being called with a nil `user?.serverAuthCode`, which prevents us from completing authentication. At the same time, `authentication?.idToken` is non-nil and `error` is nil, as if there had been no failure in authentication.

This is occurring as well in versions of our app that were built and released, suggesting that this issue was not triggered by any change in our client code.

Any ideas?

---

Update: at the end of last week this was affecting the majority of our signins, but this week we aren't seeing it anymore. Was there an issue on Google's side?

Comment: I am also having this issue. Have you found anything? Is it safe to migrate from using `serverAuthCode` to using `authentication.idToken`? And what is the difference between them? I also saw that Google documentation uses the latter.

Comment: we haven't found a solution here. we opened an issue on one of Google's issue trackers, and they told us to put it on StackOverflow and maybe one of their engineers will reply

Comment: Calling `signOut` before `signIn` seems to be a workaround.